# Calculate Sums with accumulate

Tags: scheme, sum, sequence

procedure accumulate is defined like this:

```
(define (accumulate combiner null-value term a next b)
  (if (> a b) null-value
      (combiner (term a)
                (accumulate combiner null-value term (next a) next b))))
```

problem 1: x^n
;Solution: recursive without accumulate

```
(define (expon x n)
  (if (> n 0) (* x
                 (expon x (- n 1))
              )
              1))
```

problem 2: x + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + ...+ ,calculate for given n the first n elements of the sequence.

problem 3: 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + ... + x^n/n!; calculate the sum for given x,n
*possibly incorrect solution:*

```
(define (exp1 x n)
 (define (term i)
   (define (term1 k) (/ x k))
   (accumulate * 1 term1 1 1+ i))
  (accumulate + 0 term 1 1+ n))
```

why the previous code is incorrect:

> (exp1 0 3) -> 0 ; It should be 1
>   (exp1 1 1) -> 1 ; It should be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I would say that your EXP1 procedure is operating at too low a level in being defined in terms of ACCUMULATE, and for the sake of perspicacity rewrite it instead in terms of sums and factorials:

```
(define (sum term a b)
  (accumulate + 0 term a 1+ b))

(define (product term a b)
  (accumulate * 1 term a 1+ b))

(define (identity x) x)

(define (fact n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (product identity 1 n)))

(define (exp1 x n)
  (define (term i)
    (/ (expon x i) (fact i)))
  (sum term 1 n))
```

Now to your question: the reason you are getting `(EXP1 0 3)` → 0 is no more than that you forgot to add the 1 at the start of the series, and are just computing x/1! + x^2/2! + ... + x^n/n!

Changing EXP1 to include the missing term works as expected:

```
(define (exp1 x n)
    (define (term i)
          (/ (expon x i) (fact i)))
    (+ 1 (sum term 1 n)))

=> (exp1 0 3)
1
=> (exp1 1 1)
2
```